# Force TextBox to occupy the whole remaining size in a div

Tags: css, button, html, textbox

I have a TextBox and next to it a Button with float:right, both of which inside a div of a concrete width. The Button has a concrete size defined by width and height. I want the TextBox to occupy the whole rest width left to the Button (as the Button lies at the right edge). In particular, the above div belongs to the left side of a SplitPanel. While I drag the Split, I want the TextBot to resize while Button' s size should be remain stable. I am not deeply acquainted with Css, therefore I need an indication to get over this (trivial ?) problem.

Comment: What browsers are you targeting? Are you worried about older browsers?

Comment: Of course it is crucial, some solutions won't be supported by older browsers. But if you're not worried about <IE8 and other not so new browsers (I'm thinking a few months old)

Comment: Is is possible to drop the `float` style of the button?

Comment: Yes, but what is the benefit of it? On any way the Button should be kept at the right side of the div.

Answer (score 1):

IF you're really not worried about older browsers, you can use the new `width: calc()` method:

```
input[type=text]
{
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 58px); /*add more with the other vendor prefixes*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/4Lmeg/

Comment: Ok, this would probably work, but as you have already mentioned this approach is not supported in IE7 version. Unfortunately I have to implement sth working in IE7. Excuse me for not being aware of it initially when you added the apt comment.

Comment: I know, but I can't think of another solution :)